# changing button to submit button in my javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I had this major failure in my codes, I forgot that buttons cant be isset() in PHP only submit buttons.

I used a next and prev buttons in my form, so they can next and prev the checked radio button.

but I need validation of form before going to the next radio button, when I tried converting the button to submit button it glitches and doesn't go to the next radio button.

help me convert these button codes to submit and arrange my javascript, been trying for the whole day I think I'm forgetting something again...

**HTML**

```
    <form action="reservation_next_sample.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="next[]" value="1" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" name="next[]" value="2" />

    <div id="next1" class="desc">   
            <div class="div-details">
                <h4>Event's Detail</h4>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Street
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="event_street">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Barangay
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="event_brgy">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Town/City
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="event_town_city">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Province
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="event_province">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                    <br>
<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('next');" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>                       
                </div>

<div id="next2" class="desc" style="display: none;">
<p> inside of next 2 </p>   
<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('prev');" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="dayNavigation('next');" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name$='next[]']").click(function() {
  var test = $(this).val();

  $("div.desc").hide();
  $("#next" + test).show();
  });
});

 //this is in the bla bla next and previous -->
 var index = 0;
 dayNavigation = function(direction) {
 var curr = $('input[name="next[]"]:checked');

 if (direction == 'next') {

 curr.next().attr("checked", "checked");
 curr.next().click();

} else {
  curr.prev().attr("checked", "checked");
  curr.prev().click();
}

};
</script>
```

Comment: Please clerify your question. What is it that you're trying to achieve? All I see is buttons hiding and showing div elements. What does this have to do with PHP `isset()`? Why do you want to check for them?

Comment: Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`?  It's not really clear what the problem is or what isn't working.

Comment: yes that's it! I'm so sorry to unclear statement. the next and prev button are not working when I tried to change it to submit button....

Comment: @ZeuneeLo: Define "not working".  What specifically is happening here?  What are you even submitting?  I don't see a form in this code.  If you want your buttons to be submit buttons, why does changing them to submit buttons "not work"?

Comment: I edited my post, the problem is posted....

Comment: @ZeuneeLo it's not clear what is happening nor what you expect to happen

Comment: it's alright, I posted another post like this but a clearer version. I already got an answer thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your form using jQuery example is given below. Don't change button to submit

```
$("button[type=button]").click(function(){
     this.closest("form").submit();
})
```

Instead of selecting button like **$("button[type=button]")** give button id and select particular button **$("#ButtonIdWillGoesHere")**

Comment: unfortunately it does the same problem all over when I used it. :(